# multi threading instantiate once vs per thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Having this class:

```
public class ThreadImpl implements Runnable {

 public ThreadImpl(Worker worker, AnotherWorker anotherWorker){
     this.worker = worker;
     this.anotherWorker = anotherWorker;
 }


private Worker worker;

private AnotherWorker anotherWorker;

public void run(){
 ...
 worker.doThis();
 ...
 anotherWorker.doThat();
 ...
 }
 }
```

What's the difference between these (which one is preferred and why?):

1.

```
ThreadImpl threadImpl = new ThreadImpl(new Worker(), new AnotherWorker());
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
     new Thread(threadImpl).start();
}
```

2.

```
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    ThreadImpl threadImpl = new ThreadImpl(new Worker(), new AnotherWorker());
    new Thread(threadImpl).start();
}
```

I mean new Once vs new per thread?

Comment: 1. doesn't compile. 2. doesn't compile. So none of them is preferred. If they compiled, what to choose depend on what the actual workers do, if they are thread-safe, etc.

Comment: should be `ThreadImpl threadImpl = new ThreadImpl(...);`

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what these workers do. First impression is that it is weird that you make a difference between the Runnables and the Workers.

Comment: it all depends, what if "worker" and "anotherworker" have some local fields instantiated differently in every constructor call

Comment: Worker and AnotherWorker are just some stateless classes, actually each thread fetches a file name from a blocking queue, read file contents, workers creates some Data Objects from file contents and put them on separate BlockingQueues.

Comment: Sharing the "workers" between multiple runnables may be a reasonable thing to do (if a "worker" is for example a datasource). But setting the same runnable to more than one thread is quite odd. Even if they are stateless and this would work, it seems cleaner to have them 1:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the difference between the two:

In your first example you're only creating one `ThreadImpl` instance, and therefore also only one `Worker` and `AnotherWorker` instance. Which will be shared amongst the different threads you're creating.

In your second example you're creating one for each `Thread` which should probably be the preferred way unless you have a reason to share the `Worker` objects.